# Phonegap + jqMobi / Intel App Framework causes constant screen resize

Tags: cordova, viewport, intel, jqmobi

Somehow when I try a basic example of Intel App Framework in a Phonegap project, the screen constantly keeps resizing (leaving a white space of the size of the virtual keyboard and back to 100% height).

When I try out the site in a browser everything is fine...

I tried every viewport setting that I could think of....something is causing this behaviour, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the 'afui' `div` is absolute-positioned.

The following css fixes this :

```
  #afui {
    position: static;
  }
```